# org mode sort problems with (numerical) properties

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, sorting

I use the property "pages" for the number of pages of an article or book.

There are two problems.

First:

If I use `C-c ^` to sort the items by the value of pages
`org-sort` seems to interpret the numbers lexicographically: 1<100<20<3.
Of course I need the natural order of numbers: 1<3<20<100.

Second:

If I use `C-c a m` to search for items with `pages<20` I get
the correct items and the "wrong" items: where the `pages` property is not defined.
How to ignore the "wrong" items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem, you have to use a function like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun sort-by-pages ()
 (string-to-number (org-entry-get nil "pages")))
#+END_SRC
```

then type C-c ^ f
and select the function sort-by-pages. The problem is properties in org-mode are strings, and you need this to convert them to numbers.

For problem two try: pages<20+pages<>""
the second one should eliminate the nulls.

Comment: Thanks, this solves both problems. But for the first one. Can I make the function more general?:
With one argument, the name of the numerical property, for example "pages". 


(I have more than one numerical property. It's not good to define a new function for every new numerical property.)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. I am pretty sure no arguments are allowed.